# Installing python module to python-version neutral location

Tags: python, debian, python-module, dpkg

I've built a debian package containing a python module.
The problem is that

```
dpkg-deb -c python-mymodule_1.0_i386.deb
```

show that all the files will be installed under

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mymodule*
```

This means that the end-user who installs my deb package will need to be using exactly the same version of python as I am - yet I know that my module works fine on later versions too.

In my Makefile I have the following target:

```
install:
    python setup.py install --root $(DESTDIR) $(COMPILE) --install-layout=deb
```

Where setup.py is

```
from distutils.core import setup           
setup(name='mymodule',
      version='1.0',
      description='does my stuff',
      author='Me',
      author_email='myemail@localhost',
      url='http://myurl/',
      packages=['mymodule'],
      )
```

Is there some way I can edit either the setup.py file or the Makefile so that the resulting module is installed in a python-version neutral directory instead of /usr/lib/python2.6?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Have a look at the Python packaging helper: `man dh_python2`. [This page](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging) may also help.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I did still have problems after adding "--with=python2" to my dh command line.  My build host is running python2.6 and I found that when I tried to install the resulting deb on a python 2.7 host dpkg barfed that the "Version of python on system" was wrong.

Comment: I've just had a lot more luck with dh_pysupport.  This appears to do the compile-to-python-version step in a postinst script.

Comment: That is sad because python-support has been deprecated in favor of `dh_python2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer now (thanks to the pointers from Tshepang):

In debian/rules you need to invoke dh_pysupport.

This grabs all the files installed by setup.py on the build machine in

```
$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/mymodule*
```

and puts them into a non python-version specific location in the .deb file, namely

```
/usr/share/pyshared/mymodule*
```

finally, it adds a call to update-python-modules to the postinst script, which makes sure that  the module is available on every version of python present on the target machine.